# Remove successive 0th entries in args[] for a Java command line interface?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, args

I recall seeing, somewhere, an example that stepped through String args[] by deleting the lowest numbered value(s)

```
public static void main( String args[]) {
    while (args.length > 0 ) {
    // do something and obliterate elements from args[]
    }
}
```

Obviously, a variable tracking current position in args and compared to args.length will do it; or an ArrayList made from args[]'s contents, with argsAL.size().  Am I mis-remembering an ArrayList example?  I know this is a borderline question, the likely answer is, "No, there isn't and there shouldn't be either!". Maybe I'm over-focused...

Bill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there isn't and there shouldn't be either!  Deleting from the front of an array would be a needlessly expensive way to do this.

You might be thinking of many scripting languages having a `shift` operator to dequeue the next element (perl, bash, etc).

**Edit:** Just for posterity, here's a pretty simple implementation of Queue that would allow you to "fake" the same functionality (i.e. encapsulate the cursor):

```
class ArrayQueue<E> extends AbstractQueue<E> {

    private int cursor = 0;
    private final E[] data;

    public ArrayQueue(E[] data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    private boolean inRange() {
        return cursor < data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public E peek() {
        return inRange() ? data[cursor] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public E poll() {
        return inRange() ? data[cursor++] : null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean offer(E e) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        cursor = data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        //ommitted for brevity
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return data.length - cursor;
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Queue<String> argQ = new ArrayQueue<String>(args);
    String command = argQ.poll();
    String target = argQ.poll();
}
```

**Warning: Untested**

Comment: Somebody let me know why you downvoted so I can improve my answer.  Anonymous downvotes are cowardly.

Comment: Nice, if it has to be done, this or the for loop from Ben S. are the way to go.
Thanks, folks!
Bill

Comment: ps - agree w/ Mark about downvotes. Constructive review is golden. its hard to learn from -1.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use an argument parser. My favorite is [Java Simple Argument Parser](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) (JSAP).
There is no reason to manipulate the args[] array directly. I use JSAP even for the most basic command line programs, because eventually they aren't "basic" anymore.

Comment: I'll look for it. Thanks. "basic" programs have a funny way of growing... they say you really know an organization by how it behaves in a crisis, but "trivial" and "basic" programs are probably second closest to the core.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan on popping off elements, don't use an array list since the whole array will need to be copied a bunch of times. Instead, do something like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for (String arg : args) {
        // consume arg somehow
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest the enhanced for-loop.  Then you can ignore the fact that you're looking at an array.

Comment: @Mark - if your argument syntax uses "--xx" style options, then old-school for loops may be more convenient

Comment: @Stephen C: That's a good point.  Though in that case I'd still try to avoid the index cursor and use an Iterator explicitly.  With that level of complexity I think some of the others are right in suggesting a library for argument support.

Comment: +1 for suggesting using a `for` loop (although I agree that an indexed `for` would be a better idea) rather than trying to replicate an idiom from another language.

Comment: ... although really, is the cost of popping elements going to be that high? (and to answer: I found that you'd have to have 100,000 elements before a `LinkedList` won ... and it's much more space-inefficient)

Answer (score 1):

Just use a for loop, except when you really love arraycopy's.

From a performace view it doesn't matter either, most command lines don't except more than 32k chars and I don't think your app is usually used for 16k args on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

> *...Am I mis-remembering an ArrayList example?..*

Probably or some other programming language.

Some of them have the method `shift` which when invoked does that, gives you the 0th element and removes it, something like:

```
main( args: Array[String) {
    name = args.at(0)
    args.shift
    lastName = args.at(0)
    args.shift
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be a weird way to do it.  Technically more expensive, but unless you have some crazy big command line, that really isn't even a consideration.

It has been suggested already to use a loop and this can definitely work.

For better control of command line options check out [java-getopt](http://www.freebsdsoftware.org/java/java-getopt.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a List, perhaps using `java.util.Arrays.asList(args)`. Then you have ordered traversal and easy removal of front and back elements.

Comment: That method returns an `ArrayList`, which means that popping elements off the front will cause an array copy of all other elements to move them up in the array. Far from ideal.

Comment: technically this gives you an ArrayList which has O(n) performance for removal at front... but the args[] array is small enough that performance doesn't matter.

Comment: Ack! Good point, that's what I get for not reading the docs. Shame on me! I think using some sort of LinkedList constructor with the array would be the way to go, then.

Comment: While I wasn't the person who downvoted you, I really think that you (and the people who commented above) should really test your answers first. `Arrays.asList()` does *not* return an `ArrayList`, and if you call `remove()` on it, you'll get an exception.